# Ubuntu 17.10 freeze

Tags: 17.10, freeze, logout

I've just updated from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, but I'm getting annoying problems. Sometimes the system freezes and logout me. Does anyone have the same problem? How can I solve it?

In the syslog I found:

```
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[4811]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Item :1.67/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload is     already registered
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 psensor.desktop[5420]: [2017-11-13T16:01:30] [ERR] lmsensor: impossibile rilevare il valore della     sotto funzione temp1_input: I/O error.
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 kernel: [28206.797895] gnome-shell[4811]: segfault at a70000009f ip 00007f704d044de2 sp     00007fffa3dc2fa0 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7f704d00f000+52000]
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 nautilus[24375]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-terminal-[8336]: Error reading events from display: Connessione interrotta dal corrispondente
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 update-notifier[5548]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 psensor[5420]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 indicator-multi[5177]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4811]: (EE)
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4811]: Fatal server error:
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4811]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session[4738]: gnome-session-binary[4738]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop'     killed by signal 11
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session-binary[4738]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session-binary[4738]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4811]: (EE)
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 firefox.desktop[5357]: xcb_connection_has_error() ha restituito VERO
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 thunderbird.desktop[5346]: xcb_connection_has_error() ha restituito VERO
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 wallch.desktop[5167]: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 5167, errno = 11
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[4721]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-rfkill[4960]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-    noinput'
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[4721]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[4721]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 bluetoothd[935]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.103 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 bluetoothd[935]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.103 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 kernel: [28207.066949] rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 kernel: [28207.147288] device enp0s31f6 left promiscuous mode
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-color[3747]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device     /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Chimei_Innolux_Corporation_luca_1000
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-color[3747]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device     /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Fujitsu_Siemens_Computers_GmbH_B19_5_YE6M091770_luca_1000
Nov 13 17:01:30 luca-ThinkPad-E560 kernel: [28207.179875] vboxnetflt: 0 out of 40194 packets were not sent (directed to host)
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Nautilus[4736]: sublime_text: Fatal IO error 11 (Risorsa temporaneamente non disponibile)     on X server :0.
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4844]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X     server ":0"
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4844]:       after 37089 requests (37089 known processed) with 0 events     remaining.
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[4721]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 13 17:01:31 luca-ThinkPad-E560 obexd[20812]: Terminating
```

I got problems again the day after:

```
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[3747]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Item :1.65/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload is already     registered
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[3747]: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'ClutterText'
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[3747]: clutter_text_get_editable: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[3747]: clutter_text_get_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-shell[3747]: clutter_text_set_text: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_TEXT (self)' failed
Nov 14 16:53:26 luca-ThinkPad-E560 kernel: [27629.551230] traps: gnome-shell[3747] general protection ip:7f98aef23de2 sp:7ffdb8d9de00 error:0 in     libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7f98aeeee000+52000]
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 vlc[5981]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-terminal-[15702]: Error reading events from display: Connessione interrotta dal corrispondente
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 nautilus[14634]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 update-notifier[4924]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 psensor[4519]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 indicator-multi[4234]: Error reading events from display: Pipe interrotta
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[3663]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3747]: (EE)
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3747]: Fatal server error:
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3747]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3747]: (EE)
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[3663]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 systemd[3663]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session[3679]: gnome-session-binary[3679]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by     signal 11
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session-binary[3679]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gnome-session-binary[3679]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 firefox.desktop[5607]: xcb_connection_has_error() ha restituito VERO
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 thunderbird.desktop[5602]: xcb_connection_has_error() ha restituito VERO
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 bluetoothd[1103]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 bluetoothd[1103]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 wallch.desktop[4227]: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 4227, errno = 11
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-rfkill[4018]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-color[3273]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device     /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Chimei_Innolux_Corporation_luca_1000
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 gsd-color[3273]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device     /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Fujitsu_Siemens_Computers_GmbH_B19_5_YE6M091770_luca_1000
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 pulseaudio[21642]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() ha restituito VERO
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 rtkit-daemon[3062]: Successfully made thread 21652 of process 21652 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at     nice level -11.
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 rtkit-daemon[3062]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 pulseaudio[21652]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Nov 14 16:53:27 luca-ThinkPad-E560 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[3780]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
```

Just to add that analyzing the syslog I see that there are many logs like these:

```
gnome-shell[5023]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
gnome-shell[5023]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

And searching I found this issue that may be related to it:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1497866

Comment: I'm very disappointed, I continue getting sessions killed when I log out end it happens very much (more than 5 times a day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: return to use Unity! The user session was crashing everytime the screen was locked... and working like this was not possible anymore. I hope that the new 18.04 will resolve it.